# Print to Fax with an HP Officejet 8610 on a Mac

Tags: macos, fax

I'm trying to figure out how to install the appropriate driver so that I can print to Fax on my HP OfficeJet 8610. I'm on a Mac running MacOS 11.2.3. I've seen some links online suggesting installing a driver in Printers & Scanners in System Preference. But when I try adding a printer, I don't see an appropriate driver.

Update: I found from [this site](https://machow2.com/fax-from-macos-modem/) a suggestion that this is no longer possible with MacOS after El Capitan. If anyone can suggest a free work around I'd appreciate it.

Comment: [I assume you have installed the appropriate drivers?](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-Officejet-Pro-8610-e-All-in-One-Printer-series/5367603/model/5367606)

Comment: @Ramhound I’ve attempted to but only a printer driver is installed, not a fax driver.

Comment: [It may be possible non-AirPrint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpybK.jpg). Don't recall, but think it was the HP Easy Scan app that required turning off SIP to install. The HP Printer Drivers v5.1 for macOS (1/8/21, updated certificate), Apple URL shown in the image. The whole process involved giving lots of permissions in response to pop-ups (installed on 11.1). There are drivers for both print/scan and fax, PostScript Printer Descriptions (HP Office Jet Pro 8610.ppd.gz and HP Office Jet Pro 8610 e-All-in-One Fax.ppd.gz).